Check if a record from one table exists in another and disable option
Attempt - which returns all registrations that has reportDate = CURRENT WEEK.
SELECT * 
FROM registrations 
LEFT JOIN reports on registrations.registration=reports.registration
WHERE  reports.reportDate 
  between cast(timestampadd(SQL_TSI_DAY, -(dayofweek(curdate())-2), curdate()) as date) 
  and cast(timestampadd(SQL_TSI_DAY, 7-(dayofweek(curdate())-1), curdate()) as date)

I want to achieve the following, but I do not know how to achieve it using PHP.
First, get all of "registration" from table Registrations,
then check if the registrations exist in the table Reports WHERE reportDate is equal to the current WEEK
(i.e. current week being Monday-Sunday, at todays time and date that would equal to the date 26th Aug to 1st Sept).
finally, display all the registrations in a select input (must be echoed as the select input is further down the html file) and the ones that have a reportDate = current week, have them visible but disabled.
Registrations



id
registration




1
EXAMPLE


2
EXAMPLE2


3
EXAMPLE3



Reports



id
registration
reportDate




1
EXAMPLE
2024-08-19


2
EXAMPLE
2024-08-22


3
EXAMPLE2
2024-08-22


4
EXAMPLE3
2024-08-22


5
EXAMPLE
2024-08-27


6
EXAMPLE3
2024-08-27



in the example above, EXAMPLE and EXAMPLE3 registration should be visible but disabled and EXAMPLE2 should be clickable in the select field based on the time of posting and the CURRENT WEEK of this question. Which should turn out like the code below
<select oncopy="return false" id="inspectReg" name="inspectReg" class="reg-control">
*Somewhat...a for each loop? or while?*
<option value="EXAMPLE" disabled>EXAMPLE</option> (record exists dated 27th - so disabled)
<option value="EXAMPLE2">EXAMPLE2</option> (record for current week does not exist)
<option value="EXAMPLE3" disabled>EXAMPLE3</option> (record exists dated 27th - so disabled)
</select>


This should just be a JOIN between the two tables. Please show what you tried.

@Barmar - I have updated my question, the query I have posted works... but it returns only registrations that have reportDate = CURRENT WEEK .... this is not a full solution, I need the remaining list of registrations which will be selectable ones in the select field

https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=ff08c9ee-18eb-40a4-8d41-f49ae8de3f79

Can you try this one
SELECT
r.registration,
CASE
WHEN rp.registration IS NOT NULL THEN 'disabled'
ELSE ''
END AS status
FROM
registrations r
LEFT JOIN
reports rp ON r.registration = rp.registration
AND rp.reportDate BETWEEN
CAST(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-2), CURDATE()) AS DATE)
AND
CAST(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 7-(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1), CURDATE()) AS DATE);

@Hamdallah your query returns the correct results, if you put it as an answer I can tick it. I should be able to do the rest from here.

Can you try this one
SELECT
  r.registration,
  CASE WHEN rp.registration IS NOT NULL THEN 'disabled' ELSE '' END AS status
FROM registrations r 
LEFT JOIN reports rp 
  ON r.registration = rp.registration 
  AND rp.reportDate BETWEEN CAST(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-2), CURDATE()) AS DATE) 
                    AND CAST(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 7-(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1), CURDATE()) AS DATE);


Your main mistake is your WHERE clause. If a registration has no match in reports, then you outer join an empty reports row (i.e. all columns are null). Then, in your WHERE clause, you restrict your results to rows of particular reports.reportDates. This dismisses all outer joined rows and your join is turned thus into a mere inner join. When outer joining rows, then have your criteria in the ON clause, not in the WHERE clause.
Anayway, when checking the existence of a match we prefer EXISTS over joins:
SELECT 
  rg.*,
  EXISTS
    (
      SELECT null
      FROM reports rp
      WHERE rp.registration = rg.registration 
      AND YEARWEEK(rp.reportDate, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
    ) AS has_current_week_report_date
FROM registrations rg;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/6LaRUFgs
